# What is the best way to use AngularJS?

Tags: 7

So i am wondering what would be the best way to use angular.js inside of an existing drupal 7.

I'd like to use it only on some specific nodes to display data.

should i be writing a custom module or is there something ready to use already?

Comment: You can check [AngularJS](https://www.drupal.org/project/angularjs) module which provides a bridge between Drupal and the AngularJS framework. I've not used it before so not sure, how exactly it works.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The _best way_ is always subjective. As for _is there something ready to use already_, questions asking to suggest a module are off-topic for us.